# Find the probability that girl is the captain

Tags: probability

In a class of 30 boys and 25 girls, a team of 8 students is selected for a quiz competition . Among the selected students , one is chosen as the captain. What is the probability that captain is a girl ?

Comment: What is you idea?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  do the other seven matter?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways of selecting $k$ people out of $n$, and the group consists out of two mutually exclusive subgroups, $n=m+l$. Denote $P(S)$ the probability of success, i.e. the probabilty that a girl is selected a captain out of $k$ group members. Obviously the number of girls in the team (denote it $W$) is anywhere between $0$ and $k$. Hence you need to use conditional probability:
$$
P(S)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}P(S|W=j)P(W=j)
$$
The probability to select $j$ girls out of $l$ follows hypergeometric distribution:
$$
P(W=j)=\frac{\binom{l}{j}\binom{m}{k-j}}{\binom{n}{k}}
$$
Can you handle from here?